# How to add Spinner as an item in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner, navigation-drawer

I want to add spinner as an item in my navigation drawer. Where should I put the spinner as an item? Where to inflate the layout for the spinner? Where to initialize the spinner? I want it to look like this:
[image]

This is where I add my items:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<group
    android:id="@+id/group1"
    android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_login"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_login"
        android:title="@string/login_menu_item"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_signup"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_signup"
        android:title="@string/signup_menu_item"/>
    </group>

<item android:title="@string/language">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_eng"
            android:title="@string/english">
        </item>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_heb"
            android:title="@string/hebrew">
        </item>
    </menu>
```

This is my layout with the drawer:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
          android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:title="Masü"
    />

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/textColorSecondary"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And on click of an item this is how it works:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();

    if (id == R.id.nav_login) {
        if (mIsLoggedin) {
            logout();
        } else {
            mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new LoginFragment()).commit();
        }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Step 1. Please add item in menu.xml

```
 <item
            android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_item3"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:title=""
            app:actionLayout="@layout/spinner"/>
```

Step 2. Please create layout for spinner view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Spinner xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" />
```

Step 3. set spinner data in your activity file

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.navigation_drawer_item3).getActionView();
    spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,language));
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {  
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,language[position],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
```

Step 4. please add android support design library into project if need.

Comment: Dear @kapoor, at the moment it works as it is supposed to. But, the spinner is only big as the text in it. Is there anyway to make it bigger/smaller?

Comment: create custom row for spinner and change style for spinner

Comment: navigationView.getMenu() is not wrking .

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

```
   val nv = findViewById<View>(R.id.navigation_view) as NavigationView
    val item01 = nv.menu.findItem(R.id.smarket_item)
   val spinner = item01.actionView as Spinner
   val adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
       this,
       R.array.superMarket, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
   )
   adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
   spinner.adapter = adapter

   return true


    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
}
```

Comment: Requires editing.