# Spinner always null in Menu

Tags: android, android-layout, nullpointerexception

So i followed this link to add spinner to Navigation Drawer: 
[How to add Spinner as an item in Navigation Drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37696653/how-to-add-spinner-as-an-item-in-navigation-drawer)

And here's my code:

```
@BindView(R.id.drawerLayout)
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
@BindView(R.id.toolbar)
Toolbar toolbar;
@BindView(R.id.navigation_view)
NavigationView navigationView;
@BindView(R.id.navigation_filter_view)
NavigationView navigationFilterView;
Spinner citiesSpinner;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;

private View navigationHeaderView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Iconify.with(new FontAwesomeModule());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    initNavigationDrawer();
    toolbar.setTitle("");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    navigationHeaderView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.navigation_header, null);
    citiesSpinner = (Spinner) navigationFilterView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.city_spinner).getActionView();
    citiesSpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cities)));

}
```

city_spinner layout:

```
<Spinner xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/citiesSpinner"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:gravity="center_vertical">
</Spinner>
```

navigationFilterView:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_filter_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    app:menu="@menu/search_menu">
 </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

search_menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/city_spinner"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/city_spinner"
    android:title="" />
</menu>
```

the problem is that citiesSpinner is always null

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference

Comment: Why are there two NavigationView fields?

Comment: one for left navview and one for right

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code like that..

```
   NavigationView navigationHeaderView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_filter_view);
    View hView =  navigationHeaderView.getHeaderView(0);
    citiesSpinner = (Spinner) hView.findViewById(R.id.citiesSpinner);
    citiesSpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cities)));
```